# ExtensionActivityEdge file is large, can I safely delete it?.. can I stop it's growth?

Tags: disk-space, microsoft-edge, temporary-files

The ExtensionActivityEdge file is large (3.8 GB -- C:\Users\SomeUserName\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Edge\User Data\Default)...

Can I safely delete it?..

Is there a way to configure it so that I stop/manage/limit it's growth?

Comment: i saw a thread at reddit an user said nothing happens, but your own risk